# What template to use + example code for a program that does the following; When a file is added to to directory1, move file to directory2

Tags: c#

I want to crete a program that does the following;

Give the user 2 input fields for Directory1 and Directory2 on starting the application.
When a file is added (not updated) to Directory1 -> move file to Directory2

This program needs to be running at all times and preferably move the newly added files within 5 seconds.
I'm on windows and use C#.

I'm not sure what template to use, a windows service or a windows form application?
Also example code or references are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you would like to get software recommended, you should ask your question on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Also, StackOverflow is not a site where you can request whole code, you should search that up yourself (there are enough examples in the internet).

Comment: Have you tried writing this using a FileSystemWatcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This program needs to be running at all times

This seems to point into the direction of a service.

> Give the user 2 input fields for Directory1 and Directory2 on starting the application.

This is a bit of a contradiction to the upper requirement. Either it runs all the time or it has to be explicitely started. Either way, even if you run it as a service, you will need an addtional application, that handels the GUI part, because services don't have a GUI.

Once you've figured that out, you can have a simple [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0) watching your directory. It will notify you on all sorts of events that happen in this directory (file create, delete, change, ...) Just check for the desired event and act accordingly.